# Implement CW20 token in ethereum

Tags: tokens, erc-20

What I found about [CW20 token](https://github.com/CosmWasm/cosmwasm-plus/blob/main/packages/cw20/README.md) is loosely based on ERC20 token.
Can I implement CW20 token in Ethereum platform using solidity?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the specification, it indeed looks quite similar to ERC20. Without really understanding what is CosmWasm, my guess is that yes, this can be implemented in Solidity for Ethereum. As I see it, there are just a few extra functionalities compared to ERC20.

Of course don't take my word for this, since I have no idea how CosmWasm works and how the standard is supposed to be implemented - this is just my best guess.